Какое количество времени необходимо, чтобы стать Junior C++ developer?
Я имел небольшое дело с плюсами, лишь базовый синтаксис. Какое-то время изучал язык Golang. Способность к обучению у меня есть, база минимальная тоже. Получится ли стать Junior C++ программистом за 8 месяцев, если уделять каждый день минимум 4 часа. С направлением пока точно не определился. Заранее извиняюсь за такой общий вопрос.

Такой сценарий малореалистичен. Рассчитывайте года на 2 минимум.

Если у вас есть за спиной бэкграунд и общее представление как работает ЯП, то при должном обучении вы сможете получить такой результат за такое время. Однако стоит учесть что покрыть прям общие вещи не удастся, посмотрите вакансии и сужайте круг необходимых вещей чтобы не изучить чего-то лишнего и без проблем устроиться в нужную компанию. Опять же, в разных компаниях свои минимальные критерии, где-то вас не хватит, где-то хватит с лихвой, пробуйте!

Я думаю, что да. Так что вперёд. Через 8 месяцев расскажете об успехах.

Я обычно называю цифру в год, но может и прокатит. ¯\(ツ)/¯

Это чисто мое субъективное мнение!
Я считаю, что можно, учитывая, что у вас уже есть базовые знания программирования и Junior C++ программист бывает разный, но тут много оговорок(самая большая это явно не 4 часа в день)!

Вы должны четко понять, что вы хотите изучать, т.к. если нету четкой цели, с++ можно и 20 лет учить
Вы обязательно должны писать много кода и лучше если у вас есть наставник(человек, который явно на несколько голов выше вас), который сразу будет направлять вас и сэкономит вам уйму времени. В этот код входя как работа над алгоритмическими задачами, так и коммерческий код(опыт можно получить только работая, об этом ниже)
Кроме того, есть такое понятие как soft skills, а так же например много чего, что тоже нужно знать для любого программиста, хотя это не с++, но именно как для разработчика, тот же git, docker, SQL и т.д.(список тоже зависит от вашего выбора)
Луше найти работу в этой сфере, т.к. это очень быстро прокачивает тебя, там и проект будет и наставник, и вообще будешь постоянно варится в этой среде, это очень помогает, всегда будут люди обсудить или спросить, то что тебя интересует. Еще раз повторю это явно не 4 часа в день и тем более, совмещать с другой работой!
Ну и самое главное это постоянство и желание узнать, что-то новое, никто не исключает ситуации, что можно просто дома все выучить и написать пет проекты, просто такой путь в разы тяжелее и нужно реально быть гением, но даже они не застрахованы от ошибок)

